# How do I create a shortcut folder on a linux web server?

Tags: linux, cloud-hosting

I have some folders on my web server that link to other folders.

I am wondering how this is done?

Example:
I want `http://www.example.com/public_html/css/` to point to `http://www.example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-name/css/`

Comment: your public_html is in a public_html?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

easiest way is to create a symblink like this:

```
cd /path/to/public_html/
ln -s /path/to/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-name/css/ css
```

example:

```
cd ~
ln -s wp-content/themes/theme-name/css/ css
```

Comment: +1 nice answer, no need to create logic to do this in a .htaccess or config file - which also is faster to execute

Comment: With all the .htaccess and mod_rewrite, we stop thinking about the simplest solution, and in this case, the best! nicely done! you got my +1

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [Alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)